# Image name generation

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am working on a window phone application where I am capturing `image` from the primary camera and want to generate the image name based on different parameter like `date ,time` etc. For that I am defining a method:

```
private string fnGenerate()
        {
            string fileName = "";

            // Logic to be put later.
            fileName = "testImage5.jpg";
            return fileName;
        }
```

image will come from this:

```
public void fnSaveImage(Stream imgStream, out string imageName)
        {
            imageName = fnGenerateFileName();

            BitmapImage appCapImg = new BitmapImage();
            appCapImg.SetSource(imgStream);
            IsolatedStorageFile appImgStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream appNewStream = appImgStore.CreateFile(imageName);

            WriteableBitmap appWrtBmp = new WriteableBitmap(appCapImg);
            appWrtBmp.SaveJpeg(appNewStream, appWrtBmp.PixelWidth, appWrtBmp.PixelHeight, 0, 10);
            appNewStream.Close();       

        }
```

But as of now I have hard coded the image name, but I want to generate the image name on the above parameter. Can any one help how to generate the name for `image`

Comment: add parameters to `fnGenerate` method.

Answer (score 2):

You search for

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
```

See this link for format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
private string GenerateImageName()
{
    var fileName = "Image_{0}{1}{2}_{3}{4}";
    var date = DateTime.Now;

    return String.Format(filename, date.Day, date.Month, day.Year, day.Hour, day.Minute);
}
```

When the DateTime object value is for example 16/1/2013 13:24, the method wil return: "Image_1312013_1324". You can change this to your preferences. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate your image name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Image name to be Unique, then get the following items :

1. Guid
2. DateTime.Now

Concatenate these two and hash the overall value. An finally set the hash value as your image name. This is Security-Strong.